# How do you manage a shared database in blue/green deployments?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, deployment, flyway

We have a hosted application that we are beginning to start blue/green deployments with. The application has 3 background services that will not participate in the blue/green aspect. There is only one instance of them that runs at any given time. We have two web apps under tomcat that serve as our public facing apps. One is the user interface and the other is our restful api. We have a proxy server in front so we can do the blue/green switching. All these services share a database.

My question is how do you manage blue/green deployments and not creating backwards incompatible changes to the shared database? My fear is that our blue app starts up and makes database changes that blows the green app out of the water.

By the way our apps are spring hibernate java apps that use flyway to migrate the db on startup.

Comment: I am sorry but this question is off-topic on this site; you might try on serverfault, and you are invited to post it (because it is a good question indeed) as a sample question, on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66151/devops

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611133/production-data-migration-patterns-in-continuous-delivery

Comment: You could consider either combining the two apps into one, or making the user interface connect through the API and not directly to the database. You don't necessarily want an https://martinfowler.com/bliki/IntegrationDatabase.html

Comment: Thanks for the link to that article. Martin Fowler always seems to articulate well about bad feelings that I have about designs. We are currently moving more towards microservices where each piece of the application will have it's own database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use practices that introduced in [Refactoring Practices](http://databaserefactoring.com).
these practices can help you to migrate Database with backward compatibility. for example, when you want to rename a column in blue deployment, you must have the old column until green is available.

Also, spring has a [good example](https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/31/zero-downtime-deployment-with-a-database) with details with FlyWayDB.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12982027)

Comment: @theblindprophet I am sorry. I agree with you. I edited my answer.

Comment: Good article! Sorry I'm so late to respond. We've actually been doing it this way with spring and flyway from the start and it has worked out surprisingly well. I was hoping for a magical way that this could be done to help prevent incompatible changes. It's nice to see others doing it this way as well.